# Jmeter accessing request and response headers in "Custom failure message" of Response Assertion

Tags: jmeter

In my JMeter test I have below usecase.

I have "Response Assertion" for asserting response code. Request/Response headers contain correlation id needed for debugging. I have to add "Custom failure message" with request & response headers. How to access request / response headers in custom failure message section ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Response Assertion itself there is no way to access it, however you can extract it beforehand using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor)

[image]

Once done you will be able to access request and/or response headers by putting the relevant [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into the custom failure message field

[image]